# Access other site cookies using CORS

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, browser, cross-domain

I have two servers with separate domains let say first `websiteA.com` and second one `websiteB.com`.

Now user comes to `websiteA.com` and some cookies from this website are set on the user machine.

`websiteA` loads some javascript resources from `websiteB` and the user have some cookies from `websiteB`.

`websiteB` webserver has some headers like this.

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "websiteA.com"
 access-control-allow-credentials: True
```

At this moment URL page is from `websiteA` and `websiteA` client wants to send all cookies to `websiteA` server (include `websiteB` cookies), Is that possible?

Before asking this question I search to find a solution and I find [this link](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/), so I'm runing some script like this on browser that this page is from `webisteA` that previously includes `websiteB` scripts:

```
 fetch('websiteB.com', {mode:'cors'})
 fetch('websiteA.com', {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include'
 })
```

But cookies of `websiteB` not sent to `websiteA`, It seems If `websiteB` allows `websiteA` to access cookies, It might be a way to access them. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only can read cross-cookie from same domain.

it's mean you can only read cookie sub1.sample.com from sub2.sample.com if allow from sub2.

but you can send some request contain cookies from A to B.
https://dev.to/zubairmohsin33/sending-cookies-with-cross-origin-cors-request-44m